# Execute Sql server 2017 Script on Sql Server Compact Tool Box

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

How to execute SQL Server 2017 script on SQL Server Compact tool box Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest having a look at the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page and (significantly) [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50836578/edit) your question.

Comment: Also, remove irrelevant tags. There is no mention of sqllite3 in your question.